# Rails Nginx wont load fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, fonts

I have my assets already precompiled, all are loading except the fonts which are ttf files. the assets also has the ttf.gz files. I have already checked the names and sure its the same name. Also my static images are loading just fine.

My nginx config looks like this

```
server {
     listen 80;

     root /home/usr/apps/web/public;

     location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~* ^/assets/ {
            gzip_static on;
            expires 1y;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            }

    }

     error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
     client_max_body_size 4G;
     keepalive_timeout 10;

}
```

this what the console shows

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it. Looks like the problem was on the precompilation. My fonts sass was not properly configured on getting my fonts.

Comment: what do you mean 'problem on precompilation'? I faced with same problem now, but haven't found solution yet